# How to use MatchIt in R when you already have a propensity score?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, matching, propensity-score-matching

I have dataset with the following variables:

1. y = continuous outcome variable (would like to known the difference between in outcome between groups 1 and 2)
2. group = 1 or 2 (would like to find matched subsample of the two groups so I can compute the causal difference between them)
3. score = each customer has a score; I would like to match customers based on this score.

Basically I already have the propensity score, and would like to use `matchit` to do the matching based on score and find weights. What other options are there for `distance`? I know the default is `distance = "logit"` but I can't find a list of other options. I'm looking for something like the identity option that allows me to match on `score`.

`matchit(group ~ score, data, method = "full", distance = "logit")`

Comment: Your question is interesting but rather vague... It would be nice to see what the data looks like. Here's more info on distance and methods: https://r.iq.harvard.edu/docs/matchit/2.4-20/Additional_Arguments_f.html

Answer (score 1):

You can simply supply the `score` variable to the `distance` argument to use it as the matching variable, i.e.,

```
matchit(group ~ score, data, method = "full", distance = score)
```

Note that the variables to the right of the `~` in the formula won't play a role in the matching in this way but will be present for balance checking if you use `plot` or `summary` on the output.